# Problema con el tipo de dato decimal en Doctrine2 y Symfony3

Tags: symfony3, doctrine2

Tengo una entidad que tiene tres campos de tipo decimal

```
/**
     * @var decimal
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="cantidad", type="decimal", precision = 3, scale=2)
     */
    private $cantidad;


    /**
     * @var decimal
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="precio_cuc", type="decimal",precision = 3, scale=2)
     */
    private $precio_cuc;


    /**
     * @var decimal
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="precio_cup", type="decimal",precision = 3 ,scale=2)
     */
    private $precio_cup;
```

En mi Form que maneja la entidad la tengo declarada asi..solo pongo una ..las otras estan iguales

```
->add('cantidad',NumberType::class,array(
                'scale' => 2,
            ))
```

pero a la hora de guardar la entidad en la BD me aproxima el campo a un entero..si entro 4.5 me lo aproxima a 5..en la BD los campos estan declarados como decimal tambien..

¿Cuál es el error que no lo veo?

Answer (score 0):

El problema en estos casos reside en el separador ("," o ".") dependiendo el locale configurado en symfony, la librería intl de PHP y el locale de Mysql

Si en el formulario pones un punto y te redondea a integer prueba separando con coma. Si separando con la coma también te redondea a integer entonces tendrás que revisar todos los locale.

Si solo te da error con el punto o con la coma ten en cuenta lo siguiente:

```
9.988.776,65 € Europa
$9,988,776.65 EEUU
```

Cambia el locale que falle y listo. **Cuidado con el locale del propio servidor y del PHP**

Comment: Por favor explica como cambiar el locale.